# How can I change the query generated by Hibernate for a relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

How do I change the query which is created by hibernate between two related tables?

For example, Hibernate creates a query for a relationship between two tables using a `WHERE` clause but I need a relationship between them using a `JOIN` clause instead. So I need to change the Hibernate query from:

```
SELECT supportdoc1_.TYP_FILE_SUPDC 
    FROM FUND.SUPPORT_REQUEST this_,
        FUND.SUPPORT_DOCUMENTS supportdoc1_
    WHERE this_.SUPDC_SEQ_SUPDC_SUPDC = supportdoc1_.SEQ_SUPDC_SUPDC
        AND this_.TYP_STATUS_SUPRQ <> 4
        AND 1 = 1
    ORDER BY supportdoc1_.TYP_FILE_SUPDC DESC
```

To:

```
SELECT supportdoc1_.TYP_FILE_SUPDC 
    FROM FUND.SUPPORT_REQUEST this_
        LEFT JOIN 
            FUND.SUPPORT_DOCUMENTS supportdoc1_
            ON (SEQ_SUPDC_SUPDC = SUPDC_SEQ_SUPDC_SUPDC)
    WHERE this_.TYP_STATUS_SUPRQ <> 4
        AND 1 = 1
    ORDER BY supportdoc1_.TYP_FILE_SUPDC DESC
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Please provide some actual working code as well so that others can have more insight on your actual issue. Also, you can read more about join in hibernate from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).

Comment: Light corrected grammar and formatting

Comment: What is the Hibernate code that results in the above SQL being generated for you?